# Setting a default value based on another value

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following Pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import key

class Wallet(BaseModel):
    private_key: str = Field(default_factory=key.generate_private_key)
    address: str
```

I want address to have a default_factory as a function that takes a private_key as input and returns an address. My intentions would be something along the lines of the following:

```
address: str = Field(default_factory=key.generate_address(self.private_key)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to just use `@validator` because in it you can access previously validated fields. From [the documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/):

> - validators are "class methods", so the first argument value they receive is the UserModel class, not an instance of UserModel.
> - the second argument is always the field value to validate; it can be named as you please
> - you can also add any subset of the following arguments to the signature (the names must match):
>
>   - `values`: a dict containing the name-to-value mapping of any previously-validated fields

Example:

```python
class Wallet(BaseModel):
    private_key: str = Field(default_factory=key.generate_private_key)
    address: str = "" # "" seems better than None to use the correct type

    @validator("address", always=True)
    def get_address(cls, address: str, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        if address == "" and "private_key" in values:
            return key.generate_address(values["private_key"])
        return address
```

It can be argued that `@validator` should be preferred over `@root_validator` if you just want to generate a value for a single field.

There are two important aspects of this approach that must be considered:

1. The "previously-validated fields" from the documentation means that in your case `private_key` must be defined before `address`. The values of fields defined after the field that is validated are not available to the validator.
2. If the field that is validated has a default value and you still want the validator to be executed in that case, you have to use `always=True`.

Comment: It is worth adding that if the private key is not set, get_address is still called, and will result in an undesirable exception (instead of  a validation error).

Changing this line:
`if address == "":`

To:
`if address == "" and 'private_key' in values:`

Will help with that

Comment: @Adam, thanks for the suggestion, I added it. I agree with you that it is always better to check if a given key is in the `values` dict because any previously validated field could be invalid. In this particular case `private_key` has a `default_factory`, so the `KeyError` will be caused not by not setting it, but by setting it with an invalid value (something that pydantic cannot parse as a `str`).

Answer (score 4):

For Pydantic v2 users you can use a `computed_field` decorator to achieve this behavior:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field
import key

class Wallet(BaseModel):
    private_key: str = Field(default_factory=key.generate_private_key)

    @computed_field()
    def address(self) -> str:
        return self.private_key
```

More details on [`pydantic.fields.computed_field`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.computed_field)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to acheive it using a `root_validator`:

```
class Wallet(BaseModel):
    address: str = None
    private_key: str = Field(default_factory=key.generate_private_key)

    @root_validator
    def get_address(cls, values) -> dict:
        if values.get("address") is None:
            values["address"] = key.generate_address(values.get("private_key"))
        return values
```

Not sure if this is the best way to acheieve this though